# Why error? I have problem with strtok(); so long time

Tags: c

I want to type the number in one line. It makes some problem here

I try to follow the other. I dont know what is the problem here
It noticed me 
"[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char numstr[100];
char *tok;
char *dem = " ";
main(){
    printf("Num:");
    scanf("%s",numstr);
    tok = strtok(numstr,dem);
    while(tok != NULL){
        printf("Token: %s\n",tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL,dem);
    }
}
```

it showed

input

```
Num: 55 33 66
```

output

```
Token: 55
```

I wanted

```
Token: 55
Token: 33
Token: 66
```

Comment: Why can't you just read using `%d` in loop?

Comment: Read the documentation for `scanf` and the `%s` format specifier. The go look at the docs for `fgets`.

Comment: What do you want to do with those numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one of a misuse or misunderstanding of the proper use of the `"%s"` *conversion-specifier*. `"%s"` will only read up until the first *whitespace* is encountered and then it will stop. With `"55 33 66"`, `scanf` will only read `"55"` then encounter a space and stop reading.

To read the entire line, you can use a character class `"%[^\n]"' instructing`scanf`to read all characters NOT a`'\n'` (so basically read until you reach the newline character.

But you are not done yet, you have two more tasks to perform before you are using `scanf` properly with your array. Since your array only has `100` characters, you must protect your array bound by using the *field-width* modifier telling `scanf` to read no more than `99` character, thus preserving room for the *nul-terminating* character. Secondly, you must validate the **return** of every User Input function to ensure you are processing valid data. Putting those in play you could do:

```
    printf ("Num: ");
    if (scanf ("%99[^\n]", numstr) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: user canceled input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

Your tokenization can be used unchanged, but the `type` called for by the delimiter is `const char*`, so you should update your declaration for `dem`, e,g,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char numstr[100];
char *tok;
const char *dem = " \t\n";

int main (void) {

    printf ("Num: ");
    if (scanf ("%99[^\n]", numstr) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: user canceled input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    tok = strtok (numstr, dem);
    while (tok != NULL) {
        printf ("Token: %s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok (NULL, dem);
    }
}
```

(**note:** I made `dem` `const char*` and  added the `tab` `'\t'` and `newline` `'\n'` characters as delimiters as well)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_numstr
Num: 55 33 66
Token: 55
Token: 33
Token: 66
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char numstr[100];
char *tok;
char *dem = ' ';
int MAX_CHAR = 100; // Number character to read from the input buffer


int main(){
    printf("Num:"); 
    fgets(numstr, MAX_CHAR, stdin);
    tok = strtok(numstr, dem);
    while(tok != NULL){
        printf("Token: %s\n",tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL,dem);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]"
is with the char *dem = " "; change it to char *dem = ' ';

Comment: If you define a `MAX_CHAR` for the maximum size, you should use it for the buffer `numstr` definition.